# Where does virtual memory exist in linux?

Tags: linux

As program is stored on flash/disk. For it execution, program is loaded into virtual memory and is mapped to RAM by virtual manager. During its execution process is in RAM. Then where does virtual memory exist (where it has all .text, .data, .stack, .heap)?

Comment: Virtual memory doesn't actually exist. That's why it's called "virtual" :-) It's a memory addressing technique, not an actual entity. The closest to an actual "thing" would be the MMU of the CPU (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit).

Comment: The word "virtual" means "it does not really exist, only appears to".

Comment: Well, it _does_ exist, unless Linux is configured with overcommit. Either in the form of physical RAM pages or disk clusters. Though seeing how an application usually doesn't need to care, one should probably ask "Why do you need to know, what is the specific problem you are trying to solve?".

Answer (score 3):

The virtual memory is a view of the RAM plus maybe some swap space provided by a virtual memory manager. Modern OSs have virtual memory managers and provide virtual memory to processes so that the executing program can behave as if it had a contiguous address space whose size is not limited by the actual RAM. The pages or blocks making up the virtual memory can be mapped anywhere in the RAM, so that contiguos virtual pages need to be stored in contiguos RAM areas. Or they can be swapped out to page space or swap space, waiting there until needed, whereupon they're read by the OS and mapped to some RAM page.

When you say

> During its execution process is in RAM.

This is not entirely correct. Some or all memory pages that belong to the process may be swapped out, as explained.

One more word concerning the answers and comments that say that "virtual" means it doesn't exist. This makes no sense. On the contrary, according to Webster:

> being such in essence or effect ...

Hence virtual memory is something (therefore, it exists!) that behaves as if it were memory.

Comment: As in embedded system, there is no swapping space.does it mean virtual memory will not be there?

Comment: @EmbeddedProgrammer No. As I said elsewhere, the main virtue of VM today is providing continuous address space. Hence, it is indespensable even for Un*x boxes without disks.

Comment: I would argue that *"the main virtue of VM today is"* for security.  Each process is assigned its own virtual address space, and no user process can interfere with another user process.

Comment: @sawdust A process can interfere with others, as long as it has write access to `/dev/mem`. If it has only read access, it may still try to find stored passwords, etc. However, you are still right insofar as, because any address is a virtual one, manipulation of other processes data and code simply through ordinary memory accesses is impossible. I consider this to be a beneficial side effect of the VM, whose job it is to provide an illusion of a contiguous memory starting at address 0.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual memory is just like an illusion of RAM. It uses paging to acquire additional RAM that could be used by the processes in operating system.

Comment: see its not RAM, its just virtual that means some space from anywhere, even secondary storage

Comment: Confusing answer. I agree with Ingo.

Comment: Your answer is correct @Ingo I shouldn't say 'It doesn't exist'. I shall read more about it.

Comment: how virtual memory is handle by OS as it should be logically present. where is this logically present?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual memory means memory you can access with "normal" momory access methods, although it isn't clear where the data is actually stored.

It may be

- actually in RAM
- in a swap area
- in another file (memory mapped file)

and access to it will be handled appropriately.

It is a layer of, well, virtualization so that you as a programmer don't have to worry about where the data is actually put.

The original purpose was mainly to be able to provide more memory to processes than we actually have and to extend it with means of swap space, but there are even more:

- The OS is free to use the RAM for whatever it seems necessary, e. g. caching. Under some circumstances, it may be more effective to use RAM for cache than for holding parts of a program which hasn't been used for a long time.
- Provide additional memory to a program when it requests it: if you call `malloc()`, the program's library may request the OS to provide a part of memory which can be attached seamlessly into the address space.
- Avoid stack overflow: if the stack grows larger and larger, the respective memory section may be extended as well transparently so that the program won't have to worry about it.
- A system can even do "overcommitment" of memory: if a process requests a large amount of memory, the OS may say "yes, ok", i. e. provide the memory to the program. That means in the first place "allow the program to access a certain address space area", but this address space is not immediately backed by memory. Only as soon as the program accesses this memory the mapping will be done, and if this cannot be fulfilled, the program is crashed by the Out of emory killer (at least, under Linux).

All this works by page-wise (1 page = 4 kiB) assignment of physical memory to a program, viewed via the program's address space, and this in the amount and frequency as it is needed.

Comment: The last paragraph is not true anymore with modern computers. It can be used to provide more memory than we have in the form of RAM, yet in most cases, we have more RAM than our processes need memory. The main point is the contiguos address space the VM provides.

Comment: As in embedded system, there is no swapping space.does it mean virtual memory will not be there?

Comment: @EmbeddedProgrammer No, then only one aspect is missing. Virtual memory as well involves mapping of the program's address space to a different position in physical RAM.